# Vimperator. Unable to cycle through GUI elements in some dialog boxes

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I have a problem while using Vimperator. When I try to cycle through GUI elements (buttons, textboxes, etc.) in some Firefox dialog boxes and panes pressing the Tab button focus doesn't move to the next element but just follows to the viewport.

Here's the example illustrating the bug:

1. :open http://google.com;
2. :dia addbookmark;
3. The *Add bookmark* window appears and the focus is in the *Tags* textbox;
4. Pressing the *Tab* button doesn't move the focus to the next element but passes it to the viewport instead;
5. The *Add Bookmark* window becomes absolutely unreachable through keyboard keys.

How can I solve this issue and force focus to move to a next or previous element during cycling?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.6;

Firefox 3.6.9;

Vimperator 2.3.1.

**Update**

---

Here's another one example:

1. :sb Bookmarks;
2. The *Bookmarks* pane appears and the focus is on the search box;
3. Pressing the *Tab* button doesn't move the focus to the bookmark list but passes it to 
   the viewport;
4. The bookmark list becomes practically unreachable through keyboard keys.

Comment: You know that you can use :bmark (which is on `a` by default), to add a bookmark, rather than going through the :dia stuff?

Comment: Sure, but this solution has at least one shortcoming — it's impossible to sort bookmarks out by folders.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at two settings in *about:config*:

```
accessibility.tabfocus                    (integer) = 7
browser.display.focus_ring_on_anything    (boolean) = false
```

The values given are from my current system.

Some links to more information on the possible values:
[accessibility.tabfocus](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus)
[browser.display.focus_ring_on_anything](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.display.focus_ring_on_anything)

As something to try, there's another VIM plugin for Firefox called "[Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/)" (five fingers!), which I've been very pleased with.